# php save prompt

Tags: php

Alright so I have an image the user creates. When they are finished creating the image I have a button appear that says SAVE. What I want to do is prompt the user to save the image on the page on their local disk or where ever they want to put it. I have looked on here and nothing seems to answer this directly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would use AJAX to save the data on the click of the button.  Please let me know if you would like a sample or if I have misunderstood your question.

Your save button:

Your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({

        url: 'yourSaveScript.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#yourForm').searialize(),
        error: function(data){

            alert("There was an error while inserting into the database.");

        },
        success: function(data) {

            alert("Successfully saved!");
        }

    })

});
```

Comment: Why was I downvoted with no comment..?  Show yourself downvoter!!